# PHP - What functions should be called when we post the user enter info on a page?

Tags: php

In a registration procedure, after a user has successfully registered, I need to output the user entered information such as, user name, password, security question, etc. back to a welcome page.

My question is what some good practice I should follow in order to output the user enter info on a page?

For example,

```
echo htmlentities($user_name);
echo htmlentities($user_password);
echo htmlentities($user_secrete_answer);
```

Thank you

Comment: By 'post' I take it you mean _output_ not [post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)?

Comment: You should not print the entered password on the page to prevent [shoulder surfing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_surfing_\(computer_security\)) (that’s also the reason why password input fields only show placeholders).

Comment: Hello Gumbo,

I will follow your suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: Hello Richard,

you are right and I have corrected my question.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) is fine to prevent attacks where HTML is injected (like [XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Scripting_Flaw)); in fact, you could even use just [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) that suffices to encode the special characters of HTML (remember to set the *quote_style* parameter to `ENT_QUOTES` if you want to insert the data into a HTML attribute value wrapped in single quotes).

But you should not print every data that is sent to your application. The [password is a datum that should not be returned to the user in any way](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Application_Security_FAQ#In_.22Forgot_Password.22.2C_is_it_safe_to_display_the_old_password.3F) to prevent a disclosure of this information:

> If the […] password is displayed on the screen, it can be seen by shoulder surfers. So it is a good idea not to display the password […]

Furthermore, the password should never be stored in plain text but only as a hash, if possible using an additional [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

Answer (score 2):

That's fine. There's not really anything you could do to make this more secure except using HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misread part of your question, but this may be useful to you anyways. Just make sure you escape the information as soon as you retrieve it from the POST. Doing that, you shouldn't have to worry about any HTML entities in your variables.

Depending on your implimentation of SQL, you may want to escape anything that touches the database, using a function like mysql_real_escape_string($variable).

You could get more information about that function here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Hello Donny,
I have handled all enter info from users already. Here, my focus is to make sure that I do the right thing to output the user info on a page.

thank you